# Forcing a fresh start with Postgres after updating major version

Tags: postgresql

On my Manjaro machine, I updated packages, and Postgres got updated to version 13.2-1.

Before the update, I had some databases on the previous version. Now Postgres won't start because it recognises that the existing databases are from the old version. When I attempt to start Postgres, I get:

```
~|⇒ sudo systemctl status postgresql
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL database server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2021-03-12 21:30:02 GMT; 2min 53s ago
    Process: 3173 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/postgresql-check-db-dir ${PGROOT}/data (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 12 21:30:01 xps systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL database server...
Mar 12 21:30:02 xps postgres[3173]: An old version of the database format was found.
Mar 12 21:30:02 xps postgres[3173]: See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PostgreSQL#Upgrading_PostgreSQL
Mar 12 21:30:02 xps systemd[1]: postgresql.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 12 21:30:02 xps systemd[1]: postgresql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 12 21:30:02 xps systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL database server.
```

Those databases weren't important. They were for my personal pet projects and I'm happy to delete them.

How do I do that? Postgres won't start, so I can't delete them through `psql`. How can I force the latest version to start afresh? Ignore or delete the existing databases.

Comment: try https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/pgupgrade.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yay -S postgresql-old-upgrade

how to use it: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgupgrade.html

and

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PostgreSQL#Upgrading_PostgreSQL